# mysql java executeUpdate overwrites the last row

Tags: mysql, jdbc

Java code:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(insert into answer ( content_id, question_id, user_id, answer, answer_id ) values ( ? , ? , ? , ?, ? ) ");
    stmt.setLong(1, contentID);
    stmt.setLong(2, questionID);
    stmt.setString(3, userID);
    stmt.setString(4, answer);
    stmt.setLong(5, answerID);
    stmt.executeUpdate();
```

But it doesnt add new rows in mysql db, just overwriting (incrementing primary key) of the row with the same answerID!

If i execute from mysqlworkbench manually - it add rows as expected! Table structure:

```
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `content_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `answer_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `user_id` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `answer` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `status` char(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain how you are verifying that the INSERT statement under JDBC is actually updating a row instead of inserting one. (I find that hard to believe.) One way to confirm that would be to do a `SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM answer` immediately before and after the JDBC "insert" and see if the total number of rows in the table really does stay the same.

Comment: the problem was in an another statement executed before this one. lol